# Best approach/pratice to develop a client facing UI on a Jhipster microservice model?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I created a microservice application wit a **Registry**, a **Gateway** and a **Service**(x)

What should be a best practice to create a client-face UI that consumes the APIs exposed by the services ?

Should I created a new one, or the develop my custom(fancy) UI on gateway ?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate an entity on the microservice using `jhipster:entity` in microservice folder and then import this entity using `jhipster:entity` in the gateway folder.

JHipster will ask you if you want to import the entity from a microservice, say `Yes` and then type the path (relative or absolute) to your microservice.

Comment: Ok, so I can create an entity on microservice and refer it on gateway, right ?

And how about my app UI ? Should I build it using the gateway or make it separately ?